# Asker Has Changed Course, Won't Accept Valid Answer

Tags: discussion

I had a situation recently where I answered a question ([this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189406/onclick-handler-doesnt-fire-in-dynamically-added-dom-element/189421#189421)) - 100% satisfactorily in fact, because I created a component and verified my answer before posting.

However, the user decided that they wanted to use a combination of `<aura:repeat>` and `<aura:if>` tags instead (which I happen to think is probably a good idea).

Given the context provided in the question, I simply answered the question, rather than advised the second course of action - there simply wasn't enough information.

I'm peeved, because I spent time verifying that my approach would work, and in my mind, the answer is both correct and useful - whether the user decides to use this approach to me is irrelevant.

Assuming I'm in the right, how do I inform the user about this? Does anyone have any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience you're really at the mercy of the asker here.

You won't be alone in spending time researching a problem to help find a solution for someone only for them to go off the radar entirely or leave a "thanks" comment. I can speak only for myself but that's happened to me and I don't doubt it's probably to yourself and countless others in the community.

The only thing I know you can do is comment on the question or your answer to prompt the User to accept it if you're certain it answers the question they asked. But there's a fine line between asking someone to accept an answer because as you say it does, objectively, help the community and awkwardly coming across as begging.

I'm fairly sure there's nothing the moderators, Adrian, Matt or Samuel, can do to "force" accept the answer on behalf of the User. When I was a newbie here I remember flagging an answer (not my own) because it was correct. The flag got rejected in the end.